# Can I be forced to conduct an exit interview?

Tags: resignation, netherlands, exit-interview

I gave my resignation to the current company.
HR told me that I must conduct an exit interview. But I don't want to do it since I believe it is pointless and I don't want to spend my time.

I checked my contract, but I couldn't find anything. There is only mention about to help my substitute to take up my duties.

Can they do anything if I refuse to conduct the exit interview?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130464/discussion-on-question-by-rustumir-stormbraid-can-i-be-forced-to-conduct-an-exit).

Comment: 'Conducting' would mean that you are in charge of preparing, leading and evaluating the interview. Surely you're actually just expected to show up and answer questions?

Comment: Are you still employed by the company?  In other words, are they paying you to do the exit interview?

Answer (score 152):

What are they going to do, fire you?

But in seriousness - if it is during the time you are still serving your notice, I would advise just going to the interview and keeping it brief. Your contract probably mentions something to the effect that you are required to perform tasks according to what your manager says, and this would likely be one of those tasks. Not much will happen, but if you don't want to burn bridges and be a bad leaver, just go along with it. It's probably less then an hour of your time.

If the interview would take place after you had your last day, they of course cannot force you.

Comment: I am not one of the beloved employees in the company. I know they already talk bad about me.

Comment: @RustumirStormbraid - All the more reason to go, and be professional then. You don't have to answer their questions at length.  Likely it's a formality, "what did you like here" "what didn't you like". You can be as brief or talkative as you like.  But don't burn any bridges, as is mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: "What are they going to do?" There are worse things than being fired.  One could be fired without severance.  Blowing off an exit interview could be grounds for not paying a severance.  OTH if OP's company was not paying a severance anyway, then OP can probably blow it off without consequence.

Comment: @emory Not really realistic. Failure to show up at one meeting is not going to be "cause" for dismissal.

Comment: @DJClayworth Do not worry about dismissal.  If the boss creditably promises you 6 months severance pay, then I would probably show up for the exit interview.  They are not just giving you severance pay b/c they like you.  They want something for it.

Comment: @RustumirStormbraid your current attitude may be a part of why you're not a beloved employee. Do your job. This is part of your job. FWIW, when I resigned from a place I hated and gave an exit interview happily, I was quite up front about how horrible one of my managers was. Turns out they'd had other complaints about that manager, and mine was the final straw. That manager was punished (demoted to a non-management position) after I left, according to my previous co-worker friends. The company just wants to ask you some questions. Be nice and answer them, just like we're answering yours.

Comment: @The111 you might be correct or wrong. Am I behaving like this because they behaved to me badly or they are behaving like this because I behave to them bad? Who knows?

Answer (score 96):

> But I don't want to do it since I believe it is pointless and I don't want to spend my time.

It's not your time that you're spending - you are still employed by them and on the clock. If they want to waste an hour of that time with an exit interview (rather than you doing documentation or more useful handover stuff) then that's fine.

> Can they do anything if I refuse to conduct the exit interview?

They could refuse to give you a reference (or give you a negative one). Depending on how your industry works, the could also chat with their peers at other companies, and add you to the list of people who shouldn't be hired (blacklists are usually illegal, but still happen).

---

The best thing you can do is to go to the interview, and give non-committal answers to their questions. Focus on the positives of your new job, rather than the negatives of this one.

**Do not use this as an opportunity to vent or complain about the company or individual staff**. You have **nothing** to gain from doing so, and it could potentially backfire and result in negative consequences for you (as per the above).

Comment: Are you assuming that the interview is in work time? What if it is not?

Comment: @SolarMike I've never heard of a company doing exit interviews outside of working hours. If they are asking for that, then say you'll be happy to do it, and give them your working hours as your availability. That puts the ball back in their court, and if they can't choose a time when you're available then they don't get an exit interview - but that's their choice, not your refusal.

Comment: It looks like conducting the exit interview by saying nothing is a good option.

Comment: @RustumirStormbraid you may want to think of some generic answers to give to make the process smoother. For instance, if they ask you "What don't you like about working here?", saying "nothing" or just not answering will make things a bit awkward. If you answer with something like "the commute", then that's a perfectly reasonable answer - but one that there's no real follow up or response for.

Comment: @Gh0stFish thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Gh0stFish the last company I worked for conducted the exit interview outside of working hours - three weeks after I left. But it was over lunch in a nice restaurant and they were paying so I was happy to go :-)

Comment: @Gh0stFish I had that happen to me once: I got a phone call from someone with my former employer after I'd started working for my new employer suddenly asking for an exit interview. They were weirdly aggressive about getting it done on a specific day even though I kept telling them I was going to be at a work conference. I ignored any calls I got while working at the conference and they never tried again.

Comment: @AaronF, very strange, but at least they made it worth your while.

Comment: Hey I don't know who needs to read this, like in the year 2024 or something, but read that bolded sentence again. It will be true forever.

Answer (score 75):

## Legal and practical issues addressed at exit interview

You said:

> since I believe it is pointless

You may be incorrect.

An [exit interview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_interview) is often the time when the [Human Resources department](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_resources) will cover important legal and practical issues.

- You likely will sign a formal agreement about your precise date-time of separation.
- You will discuss returning any company-owned equipment (tools, keys, laptop, mobile phone, etc.).
- They will remind you of your obligations under any [non-compete agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-compete_clause) if you had signed one.
- They may explain compensation policies about cashing out accrued vacation time, and how your final paycheck will be handled such as where you want it mailed.
- Information and documents are conveyed relating to stock options, pensions, and retirement accounts.
- In the United States, they will explain signing up for continuing insurance coverage under [COBRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidated_Omnibus_Budget_Reconciliation_Act_of_1985).

So attending the **exit interview is quite beneficial to you**. This is the opportunity to wrap up all these legal and practical matters as quickly and simply as possible.

Take all the time you need to read through any documents that they ask you to sign. Do not feel rushed. If you are at all uncomfortable with any document, or do not understand it, explain that you cannot sign at the moment, and ask for a copy to take with you. Then you can study further, or consult an attorney or such.

As others have said, you may be invited to give feedback about your experience with the job and company. And as others cautioned, this is a fruitless formality that should be kept short with a polite simple statement. This part may take *less than one minute*.

The HR person does not *really* care about the motivations for your departure, so there is no grilling or interrogation. They just need to tick some box in their HR software form. Generally, you are under **no obligation to provide them any feedback** or commentary. So one of those boxes on that form will be “No comment”, and you may choose that option.

If you have any pending or potential legal issues with the company, check with your attorney as to what to say or not say during the exit interview meeting.

Comment: +1: this is usually what exit interviews are - basically a summary of what's going to happen, when and how you have to turn stuff in (if that wasn't already done) and other minutia, and if any special arrangement is not covered, a good chance to ask

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza -- indeed. And "exit interview" is an unfortunate name for it, because it doesn't really capture what the event is about.

Comment: THIS is indeed what happens and why it's important.  As for the "fruitless formality" around the soft questions such as what you (dis)like, you have NO obligation to answer those: "If it's ok with you, there is little I have to say" is a clear signal and a safe & healthy answer if you are leaving with any feelings of contempt. As for legal obligations, you generally have NO obligation to reveal your plans but you can reassure them that you are aware of your legal obligations.

Comment: "Take all the time you need to read through any documents that they ask you to sign" _and don't sign **anything** you aren't 100% sure about and comfortable with._ It's always OK to say, "I'm not willing to sign this until I've run it past a lawyer." Most good lawyers would probably say not to sign anything at all unless it's just the instructions on where to deliver your final check. Definitely don't sign any NDAs or non-compete forms at this point, anything that implies any wrongdoing on your part, or anything that suggests that your final check will be tied to some additional requirement.

Comment: Just don't sign anything. There is no reason to sign anything at an exit interview.

Comment: @PeteBecker right? I'm personally campaigning to rename it "offboarding", it reflects better what happens, IMHO

Comment: As per the Wikipedia page you linked to, "the purpose of [exit interviews in business] is to gain feedback from employees in order to improve aspects of the organization, better retain employees, and reduce turnover". It then seems contradictory for questions in line with this purpose to "take less than one minute". If you're invited to a meeting focused around the various legal and practical matters around leaving, then one might argue **this isn't an "exit interview"** (although I can't comment on whether or not companies actually use this term for such meetings).

Answer (score 8):

I would think that your contract would state something along the lines of performing tasks or about being professional but either way I don't see any harm in going there. If you today have a good reference why waste it?

The only con I see of going on it is that you feel that you wasted a little bit of time.

The cons of not going I see first and mostly a red flag on you being unprofessional and if you are not moving far away it may happen that one of those people will end up your boss and then you want them to have a good memory of you

Answer (score 7):

I would say one thing,

**DO NOT Sign Anything** that may limit your ability to earn income without a **comparable consideration**

Comment: Right.  They can't say "you can't leave the company before you sign this document" unless they are offering you a severance package conditional on your signature.  They time for an employer to limit your rights is up-front when you start, not when you leave.  The only thing you should sign is something that says "I came to the exit interview, I gave you back everything that was needed and I was given a copy of whatever I signed when I started in the company"

Comment: @Flydog57 Totally agree

Comment: Came here to say exactly this. Do not sign anything at an exit interview.

Comment: Do employers often ask employees to sign such things at exit interviews specifically?

Comment: @NotThatGuy  i had one former employer requiring to sing a new non compete at exit interview. Heard its occasionally happen to others as well

Comment: @NotThatGuy: YES! It's such a classic dirty move that this site has a number of questions on the exact topic - employees leaving a job where they had no NDA or non-compete, and the employer pulls a new NDA or non-compete on them as part of the exit process, hoping they'll be foolish enough to sign something for no consideration.

Answer (score 2):

I would go and listen to them talk and give them whatever rubbish answers they want to make the whole thing end as quickly  as possible. They may very well waste your time but you are on the way out so they won't be wasting it for much longer. You answer there question in a non confrontational way. Don't be sarcastic or snide, let the tone of your voice be as neutral as possible. I would give them what they want because after all they did employ you for however long you worked there.

You were probably able to feed and clothe yourself while you were working there, this should at least have earned a little bit of respect from you. You may have been unhappy and they may have treated you poorly but even bad jobs can be a means to some sort of career end.

If you flatter them it does not matter that your flattery is not sincere. I would even go and thank them for working there. This may be the most insincere thing you ever say, but if there is just a possibility of some future benefit arisesing from it why not do it?

What you have to realise is that manipulation that does not negatively affect other people is not a bad thing. If you can gain some benefit in life by saying something then you do it. If you gain some benefit from remaining silent then that is what you do it. You work with the personalities you come in contact with as to best benefit yourself. This is selfish, but as long as it does not negatively affect others then it is not bad.